# How can I enhance this python code to do a natural sort of a list of FQN hostnames and ip addresses?

Tags: python, sorting, ip-address

Say I have

```
apple.berry.cherry.za
100.100.100.100
100.100.100.20
apple.berry.banna.au
```

and I want

```
100.100.100.20
100.100.100.100
apple.berry.cherry.au
apple.berry.banna.za
```

I have the following python code which sorts FQN hostnames the way I want, but it only does alpha-numeric sorting on IP addresses:

```
#!/bin/python
from fileinput import input
for y in sorted([x.strip().split('.')[::-1] for x in input()]): print '.'.join(y[::-1])
```

I can add a  function to convert a triplet to an integer:

```
def atoi(text):
    return int(text) if text.isdigit() else text
```

But because I don't know python, I don't know how to call atoi() on each element of the list before it is sorted.
How to do?

Comment: Why is `cherry` sorted before `banna`?

Comment: @unutbu hostnames sorted right to left, starting with domain name

Comment: And integers are sorted before strings?

Comment: Your solution sorts numeric IPs right-to-left as well. Is that expected?

Comment: In default alphabetic sorting, digits are before letters. I don't care if numbers come before or after strings. My example shows IPs left to right only because I expect that's what would happen if I inserted atio() into the one-liner code.

Comment: But if you do an alphabetic sort, 100 comes before 20. So if I understand it right, you would want `int` before `str`. `int` sorted numerically and `str` alphabetically? And sort by `.` delimited fields right to left. Does that sound like an accurate description of "the way I want" from the question?

Comment: Yes, thanks @OndrejK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a function to each element of the list by using [map filter](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html). So it'd be:

```
for y in sorted([map(atoi, x.strip().split('.')[::-1]) for x in input()]):
    print '.'.join(y[::-1])
```

**Edit:** As pointed by @Slam, if you decide to use Python 3 one day, translating the foregoing code won't be straightforward. It doesn't allow you to compare ints and strings.

Comment: Use `(...)` for print arguments in Python 3. OP clearly uses Python 2 though.

Comment: print is not a problem at all. py3 will raise error for int <-> str comparison

Comment: Ah, you're totally right. I'll add a note to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect ipv4 only and this is on-time utility script, you can try dirty hack like

```
sorted(lst, key=lambda x: [i.zfill(3) if i.isdigit() else i for i in x.split('.')][::-1])
```

If not, you *probably* wont end up with one-liner. You need natural sorting for digits, which is not available out of the box